# Conjecture about some group semiring representations ( and roots of unity ).

Tags: group-theory, matrices, ring-theory, diagonalization, roots-of-unity

Let $\Bbb R_+=[0,\infty)$ be a semiring.  $\Bbb R_+[C_n]$ is the group semiring formed by the semiring $\Bbb R_+$ and the cylic group $C_n$.

Let $\Bbb R_+[X_n]$ be the polynomial semiring.
(polynomials of $X_n$ with positive real coef. )

$\Bbb R_+[C_n]$ is isomorphic with $\Bbb R_+[X_n]/(1+X_n+(X_n)^2+...+(X_n)^{n-1})$

For example $\Bbb R_+[C_3]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R_+[X_3]/(1+X_3+(X_3)^2)$.

We can give the isomorphism explicit by giving $ X_3 = ( 1^{1/3} )$

$1^{1/3} = \exp\left(\frac{2 \pi i}{3}\right)$

Thus we write : $\Bbb R_+[C_3] => X_3 = (1^{1/3})$

Likewise we get $\Bbb R_+[C_4] => X_4 = ( 1^{1/4} , 1^{2/4} )$

Or in matrix form : $X_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 1^{1/4} & 0  \\ 0 & 1^{2/4}  \end{pmatrix}$

Let $(*, * , ... , * )$ denote the so-called diagonal matrix :

$\begin{pmatrix} * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & * & \cdots& 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & * \end{pmatrix}$

(by which I mean a square matrix filled with zero's apart from $ * $ on the diagonal.)

The question becomes what the explicit isomorphisms for $X_n$ look like.

$\Bbb R_+[C_n] => X_n = ( "?" , "?" , "?" , ... )$

($"?"$ are roots of unity but which ones ? )

The simplest conjecture is

$M[C_{2n}] => X_{2n} = ( 1^{1/2n} , 1^{2/2n} , 1^{3/2n} , 1^{4/2n} , ... , 1^{n/2n} )$

$ \Bbb R_+[C_{2n+1}]$  => 
$X_{2n+1} = ( 1^{\frac{1}{2n+1}} , 1^{\frac{2}{2n+1}} , 1^{\frac{3}{2n+1}} , 1^{\frac{4}{2n+1}} , ... , 1^{\frac{n}{2n+1}} ) $

But is this conjecture true?

Comment: What is the use of representing $X$'s with matrices (when just the first component suffices)? Why do you think $M[C_n]$ is isomorphic to $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$? (It isn't; after tensoring against $\Bbb R$ over $M$ the $\Bbb R$-dimension of the former is one greater than that of the latter.)

Comment: @anon I believe $M[C_2]$ is isomorphic to the reals $R$ and also isomorphic to $M[X]/(1+X)$ ? The reason is that for $M[C_2]$ we have magnitude and + or - sign from $C_2$ ; so we get the reals. And $M[X]/(1+X)$ with $X = -1$ also seems like magnitude with a + or - sign ( because of $/1+X$ ).
Further $M(C_3)$ is 3 dimensional and so is $M[X]/(1+X+X^2)$.
By induction I believe $M[C_n]$ is isomorphic to $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$. How could this be wrong ??

Comment: @anon the matrix form of the $X$'s is just an option. I got negative comments about the use of $(*,*)$ and also comments that showed confusion. So I mentioned the matrix to clarify and/or simplify the question to some.

Comment: $M[C_2]$ is not isomorphic to the reals. It's nonzero elements have no additive inverses, so it's not even a ring, and as a semiring it has zero divisors. But $M[X]/(X+1)$ is indeed isomorphic to the reals $\Bbb R$. The semiring $M[C_3]$ only has a real dimension *after* tensoring with $\Bbb R$; it is not by itself a vector space. After tensoring with $\Bbb R$, though, $M[C_3]$ will have dimension three whereas $M[X]/(1+X+X^2)$ will have dimension *two*, not three.

Comment: Instead of asking how you could be wrong, you should be asking *how you could be right* - all of your reasoning and justification and argument so far has been unrigorous and vague at best, and simply make-believe at worst. You need to understand what all of these concepts mean. For example, you say that $C_2$ gives $+/-$ "signs" in $M[C_2]$, but since these two "signs" don't *cancel* upon addition with each other, is that really an accurate way of thinking about them? (No, it isn't.)

Comment: @anon Ok. In that case its $M[X]/(1+X+X^2+...)$ that my question is about. In other words if I replace those $M[C_n]$ with $M[X_n]/(1+ X_n + ... + X_n^{n-1})$ Can you answer the question ?

Comment: I want to make another point: there is no use in putting a subscript of $n$ on $X_n$. I can tell you right off the bat that $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$ is not isomorphic to $M[\zeta_n]$, because the former has zero divisors whereas the latter (which is $\Bbb C$) doesn't. One thing that's interesting is that $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb R}[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$ (via a natural inclusion map), and I detailed how this ring looks in my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $M[C_n]$ and $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$ are not the same. For one thing, the sum of the first $n$ powers of a generator of $C_n$ (starting with $X^0:=1$) is nonzero by the group semiring construction, whereas the sum of the first $n$ powers of $X$ is zero in $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$; as another thing, the nonzero elements in $M[C_n]$ have no additive inverses, whereas we will see that the quotient polynomial semiring is actually a ring.

In fact, $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})\cong{\Bbb R}[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$. A nice clean isomorphism is induced simply from $M\hookrightarrow {\Bbb R}$; to see that this semiring homomorphism is surjective, try proving that every coset in ${\Bbb R}[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})$ can be represented by a polynomial with positive coefficients (first write a representative with $\deg<n$, then add $1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1}$ to it sufficiently many times). My explanation in your previous question leads to

$${\Bbb R}[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})\cong\begin{cases}{\Bbb C}^{(n-1)/2} & n~{\rm odd} \\ {\Bbb R}\times{\Bbb C}^{n/2-1} & n~{\rm even}\end{cases}$$

as an $\Bbb R$-algebra. If $n=2$ then $M[\zeta_n]=\Bbb R$, else for $n>2$, $M[\zeta_n]=\Bbb C$ (since there will be an $n$th root $\zeta$ with negative real part so $\zeta+\zeta^{n-1}\in M[\zeta_n]$ is a negative real) as subsemirings of $\Bbb C$.

Therefore, $M[X]/(1+X+\cdots+X^{n-1})\cong M[\zeta_n]$ if and only if $n=2$ or $3$. [[Moreover if $A$ is any diagonal complex matrix whose entries are $n$th roots of unity at least one of which is primitive, then $M[A]\cong M[\zeta_n]$ (and this is why working with matrices is superfluous decoration which only serves to obscure what's really going on in this case).]] Correction: if $A$ is a diagonal matrix comprised of at least one of each conjugate pair of $n$th roots of unity (excluding $1$), then the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $\Bbb R$ will be $X^{n-1}+\cdots+X+1$, in which case $$M[A]\cong{\Bbb R}[A]\cong{\Bbb R}[X]/(X^{n-1}+\cdots+X+1)\cong M[X]/(X^{n-1}+\cdots+X+1)$$ The matrix conjecture is therefore true.